# How do I use service account and API key separately to use BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

How do I use service account and API key separately to use BigQuery?

I would like to access to BigQuery API from server application.
My Server application would like to use only one authorization key to access to BigQuery API.
I think that I can select following 2 way.

- API key
- Service Account

Above key is described as following in google developers console.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use service account for BigQuery as that's easier to use, and lots of examples are based on that.

Also the CLI tool can be setup to use a service account so you have an advantage there.

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com --key-file ~/.bigquery.v2.p12
```

Comment: Thank you!
I will use service account.

Although, I wonder what kind of purpose does "API key" suite?

Comment: Yes, I am second to ask what is the meaning of `API key` choice in relation to BigQuery.

Comment: Api key is good when you have a 3rd party user using their account, and giving their api key to run a software they didn't built. If I build my own, I use service account.